# How to query overlapping appointments while excluding one record?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to check for overlapping appointments, but excluding the current record, but I can't seem to get a query that will work.

```
     SELECT COUNT(1) as tCount 
     FROM appointment 
     EXCEPT appointment.appointmentId = 3
     WHERE appointment.`start` >= "2019-02-06 08:15:00.000" 
     AND appointment.`end`  <= "2019-02-06 08:30:00.000"
```

This works just fine when I take out the 'except' line, and I can get the right number of records.  I'm just not certain how to exclude one record.

[image: Database Schema]

This is the error I am getting.

```
[Warning, Error code 1,064, SQLState 42000] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXCEPT appointment.appointmentId = 3' at line 4
```

Here is the java part that calls the SQL:

```
  String overlapCheck = "SELECT COUNT(1) as tCount \n" +
                        " FROM appointment \n" +
                        " WHERE appointment.`start` <= \"" + start +       
                        "\" AND appointment.`end`  >= \"" + end + "\""
                    + " AND appointment.appointmentId <> \"" + check + "\"" ;     

                System.out.println(overlapCheck);

                ResultSet value = accessDB(overlapCheck);
                        int number = 0; 
                        if(value.next()){           
                           number = value.getInt(1) ;
                         }

                System.out.println("The number over overlapping appointments is " + number );

                if (number >= 1){ 
                    errorLabel.setText("Overlapping appointment times, please adjust.");
```

And a picture of the database data:

[Database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtD6z.png)

The query seems to be working correctly when I check for overlaps.  I'm intending them to have no overlapping at all.

Comment: without seeing your schema and source data in the table, and your expected output it's making it a lot harder for us to help you with any certainty. Please provide a complete example that we can use. We can't read your screen, your disk...or your mind. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I added a schema, but the output should be an int, and I get the error that my syntex is wrong.

Comment: Well again, to make the example complete, you should show us the full error. And we still need the source data and expected output. Yes it should be an int...that's obvious from the code. But the important thing is, based on the sample source data, what do you expect the _value_ of the int to be?

Comment: Anyway there is no such keyword as `EXCEPT` in mysql, so I should imagine that's the source of your problem. Try `AND appointment.appointmentId <> 3` in your WHERE clause instead.

Comment: 0 if there are no overlapping appointments, otherwise the number of overlapping appointments.  

In this particular case it should be 0.

Comment: Which particular case? Again, we have no data from which to derive the particular case.

Comment: You sure that your **MY**sql supports EXCEPT? I think wou should move it into WHERE clause as ' AND appointment.appointmentId != 3'

Comment: @ADyson: Are you sure? It's from ANSI 92 I think (it was supported in mysql 3.x), mentioned in mysql manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: @fifonik you know what, you may be right. Perhaps my knowledge on that particular point is a little out of date. Apologies.

Comment: OH!  Thank you ADyson, that worked perfectly!

Simonare, I am trying, just new at asking questions on here.  

Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no sample data provided from which we can be sure that the rest of the query is correct, but the one thing certain is that `EXCEPT` is not a valid keyword in MySQL. You may have come across it when working with Microsoft SQL Server, but it's not a standard across all SQL implementations.

In this case you can replace it quite simply with an extra clause in the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as tCount 
FROM appointment 
WHERE appointment.`start` >= "2019-02-06 08:15:00.000" 
AND appointment.`end`  <= "2019-02-06 08:30:00.000" 
AND appointment.appointmentId <> 3
```

This will fix your syntax error. Assuming the rest of the logic meets your requirements then your query should now work as expected.

Comment: @Strawberry I suspect the same, hence my last paragraph. But I can't easily prove it due to lack of info in the question. Might depend a bit what "overlapping" means exactly in this context.

Comment: Well, I added some more info but it seems to be working when I test it.

Comment: @marilyn it seems odd to me that an appointment isn't considered to be overlapping if it starts before another ends, but ends after. :-? Unfortunately, I don't *do* pictures of data

Comment: oh!  Okay, interesting.  You are right, except that I have already limited appointment start times, and lengths so that shouldn't be possible- I'll double check everything though.

How was I supposed to upload the data?

Comment: @Marilyn you probably want to tag Strawberry in your comment or else they won't see it. I only see it because it's my answer. Anyway, data is _text_, so we'd expect you to paste it as text and then use the [tools available](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format it nicely. Images are useless because they're often compressed and hard to read, there's a chance the the external site used to host them might die in future (making the question less useful to other readers), and most importantly we can't copy/paste the data to use in answers or to use for testing.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will definitely improve my question asking skills.  Thank you for being so patient with me!  I really appreciated it.